# How to give friend access to git repository without giving command line access?

Tags: xcode, macos, git, ssh

I have some git repositories running on my server and I would like to give a friend read/write access to one. That's simple: I add him as a user, give him SSH access, and change the permissions to the repository folder.

Everything works fine; I'm able to clone the git repository **using Xcode** and change things (`ssh://www.example.com/repo.git`). However, **I do not want him to have command line access**. If I recall correctly, Github does not give command line access to those who SSH in.

I'm using Snow Leopard Server. Is this more of a server issue or a git issue? Do you have any idea where to begin? Setting the user's `Login Shell` to `none` (as opposed to `/bin/bash`) cuts off access to everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Git server software is a fine idea, but it's not necessary if you'd rather stick with vanilla Git.

The `git-shell` tool that comes with Git can help you prevent your users from gaining shell access. In short, you can set it as your users' login shell (replacing bash, csh, or similar). They'll be able to run the standard Git commands, but nothing else.

See [Setting Up the Server](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server) in Pro Git for instructions.

Comment: I'm running this: http://code.google.com/p/git-osx-installer/. Sorry if stupid question, I just started using git today, but will the instructions on that link work with this?

Comment: Seeing as OS X is UNIX-based, I would think that changing a user's login shell should work just fine, but I can't say for sure. When you set the Login Shell, was that in a GUI? Was there an option for `git-shell`?

Comment: I got it to work correctly (`/usr/bin/git-shell`) and since the user doesn't have a home directory (and therefore the home directory doesn't have the `git-shell-commands` folder), he can't even SSH in, which is fine. How would you manage access to the repositories in my situation? Right now I am limiting access to different repositories based on file system permissions. Is this the best way to do it or is there something better built into `git` (not interested in Gitolite since it manages access through keys and I want to manage access by username/password)? Thanks.

Comment: I'm no expert, but that seems like a fine solution to me. Tools like Gitolite can offer more advanced access control if that's important to you.

Answer (score 1):

try to use a git server software like gitolite, it will provide access to git repo but not shell